# Java - How can I merge 2 lists based on a third?

Tags: java, algorithm, list, collections, merge

I try to solve a problem since 2 days and my algorithm seems too complex. 
I need to produce 1 list of data that merge 2 ordered lists (named below "list A" and "list B")
This merge must be based on a reference ordered list to identify where each element will be placed.
If List A and List B contain same value for a rank, I need to keep only one of them

Ex :

> Reference list    : 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
>   List A            : 2 | 4 | 6
>   List B            : 1 | 4
>
> Expected result : 1 | 2 | 4 | 6

Code

```
private static List<String> mergeListsUsingRef(final List<String> listRef, final List<String> listA, final List<String> listB) {
    final List<String> res = new ArrayList<>();

    final Iterator<String> listRefIterator = listRef.iterator();
    final Iterator<String> listAIterator = listA.iterator();
    final Iterator<String> listBIterator = listB.iterator();

    String a = listAIterator.hasNext() ? listAIterator.next() : null;
    String b = listBIterator.hasNext() ? listBIterator.next() : null;
    while (listRefIterator.hasNext() && (a != null || b != null)) {
        final String ref = listRefIterator.next();

        if (a != null && ref.equals(a)) {
            res.add(a);

            if (b != null && ref.equals(b)) {
                b = listBIterator.hasNext() ? listBIterator.next() : null;
            }
            a = listAIterator.hasNext() ? listAIterator.next() : null;
        } else if (b != null && ref.equals(b)) {
            res.add(b);

            b = listBIterator.hasNext() ? listBIterator.next() : null;
        }
    }
    return res;
}
```

Now I have to complexify the initial problem. The main difficulty comes from the possibility of having same values several times into each list.
This means finding which positions are allowed for duplicate values.

Let's imagine some examples to illustrate that (with 4 that appear two times into the reference list)

> Reference list    : 1 | 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>   List A            : 2 | 3 | 5 | **4** | 7
>   List B            : **4** | 7 | 8
>
> Expected result : 2 | 3 | 5 | **4** | 7 | 8
>
> > **Explaination :**
> >     In List A : regarding to reference list, 4 is between 5 and 7 so 4 can be placed only at the second rank
> >     In List B : regarding to reference list, I can't determine where 4 is (first or second rank)
> >     So, List A determine the 4's position at the second rank

---

> Reference list    : 1 | 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>   List A            : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 7
>   List B            : **4** | 7 | 8
>
> Expected result : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 7 | 8
>
> > **Explaination :**
> >     In List A : regarding to reference list, 4 is between 3 and 5 so 4 can be placed only at the first rank
> >     In List B : regarding to reference list, I can't determine where 4 is (first or second rank)
> >     So, List A determine the 4's position at the first rank

---

> Reference list    : 1 | 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>   List A            : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 7
>   List B            : 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>
> Expected result : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>
> > **Explaination :**
> >     In List A : regarding to reference list, 4 is between 3 and 5 so 4 can be placed only at the first rank
> >     In List B : regarding to reference list, 4 is between 6 and 7 so 4 can be placed only at the second rank
> >     So, 4 must be placed at the first and second rank

---

> Reference list    : 1 | 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | **4** | 7 | 8
>   List A            : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 7
>   List B            : 6 | 7 | 8
>
> Expected result : 2 | 3 | **4** | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8
>
> > **Explaination :**
> >     In List A : regarding to reference list, 4 is between 3 and 5 so 4 can be placed only at the first rank
> >     In List B : 0 occurrence of 4
> >     So, List A determine the 4's position at the first rank

My previous code does not work to deal with these difficult cases.
Does anyone know how to help me to advance its implementation ? :)

***EDIT :*** 
Main Java to validate the implementation :D

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
System.out.println("EX 1 : ");
        List<String> refList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "4",
                "7", "8");
        List<String> listA = Arrays.asList("2", "3", "5", "4", "7");
        List<String> listB = Arrays.asList("4", "7", "8");
        List<String> mergeListsUsingRef = mergeListsUsingRef(refList, listA,
                listB);
        System.out.println("Expected : 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 7 | 8 ");
        System.out.print("Actual : ");
        for (String res : mergeListsUsingRef) {
            System.out.print(res + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("EX 2 : ");
        refList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "4", "7", "8");
        listA = Arrays.asList("2", "3", "4", "5", "7");
        listB = Arrays.asList("4", "7", "8");
        mergeListsUsingRef = mergeListsUsingRef(refList, listA, listB);
        System.out.println("Expected : 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7 | 8 ");
        System.out.print("Actual : ");
        for (String res : mergeListsUsingRef) {
            System.out.print(res + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("EX 3 : ");
        refList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "4", "7", "8");
        listA = Arrays.asList("2", "3", "4", "5", "7");
        listB = Arrays.asList("6", "4", "7", "8");
        mergeListsUsingRef = mergeListsUsingRef(refList, listA, listB);
        System.out.println("Expected : 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 4 | 7 | 8 ");
        System.out.print("Actual : ");
        for (String res : mergeListsUsingRef) {
            System.out.print(res + " | ");
        }
        System.out.println("");
        System.out.println("----------------------------------");
        System.out.println("EX 4 : ");
        refList = Arrays.asList("1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "4", "7", "8");
        listA = Arrays.asList("2", "3", "4", "5", "7");
        listB = Arrays.asList("6", "7", "8");
        mergeListsUsingRef = mergeListsUsingRef(refList, listA, listB);
        System.out.println("Expected : 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 ");
        System.out.print("Actual : ");
        for (String res : mergeListsUsingRef) {
            System.out.print(res + " | ");
        }
    }
```

Comment: I don't understand what's the rule for cases where same value occurs multiple times in the reference list.

Comment: Looks Like intersection of Reference List with List A and List B,
IF that is the case you can use HashSet with RetainAll method

Comment: Yes, intersect the two lists (reference list isn't relevant at all?!) ... maybe using sets. And yes, I agree: your requirements arent clear to me. Try to find example where the reference list actually matters.

Comment: I am assuming order of elements also matter here.

Comment: Why is the first 4 suppressed in EX 1, but not in EX 3? I don't get the logic. I can't infer the rules from what you've said.

Comment: @Andreas : I added some explainations, I hope it will be more precise

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this solution will work - it preserves the order of the lists, and gave the correct answers to all the samples shown above. By keeping the reference list as a hashMap of indexes, it allows to quickly query for any two integers if one can appear before the other by the reference. I added a printout in a main to test.

```
 public class ListMergeByRef {

    public Map<Integer, List<Integer>> refMap = new HashMap<Integer,List<Integer>>();
    public ListMergeByRef(List<Integer> reference) {
        int elementIndex = 0;
        for (Integer element:reference) {
            List<Integer> refListPerElement = refMap.get(element);
            if (refListPerElement == null) {
                refListPerElement = new ArrayList<Integer>();
            }
            refListPerElement.add(elementIndex);
            elementIndex++;
            refMap.put(element, refListPerElement);
        }
    }

    public List<Integer> mergeLists (List<Integer> first, List<Integer> second) {
        int firstIndex = 0;
        int secondIndex = 0;
        List<Integer> merged = new ArrayList<Integer>();
        while (firstIndex < first.size() || secondIndex < second.size()) {
            if (firstIndex == first.size()) {
                merged.addAll(second.subList(secondIndex, second.size()));
                return merged;
            } else if (secondIndex == second.size()) {
                merged.addAll(first.subList(firstIndex, first.size()));
                return merged;
            } 

            if (first.get(firstIndex).equals(second.get(secondIndex))){
                merged.add(first.get(firstIndex));
                firstIndex++;
                secondIndex++;
            }
            else if (isElementAllowedBeforeOther(first.get(firstIndex), second.get(secondIndex))) {
                merged.add(first.get(firstIndex));
                firstIndex++;
            } else {
                merged.add(second.get(secondIndex));
                secondIndex++;
            }
        }
        return merged;
    }

    public boolean isElementAllowedBeforeOther(Integer firstElement, Integer secondElement) {
        List<Integer> firstElementIndexes = refMap.get(firstElement);
        List<Integer> secondElementIndexes = refMap.get(secondElement);
        if (firstElementIndexes == null || firstElementIndexes.isEmpty()) return false;
        if (secondElementIndexes == null || secondElementIndexes.isEmpty()) return true;
        if (firstElementIndexes.get(0) < secondElementIndexes.get(secondElementIndexes.size()-1)) return true;
        return false;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Integer> ref = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {1,2,3,4,5,6,4,7,8});
        List<Integer> first = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {2,3,4,5,7});
        List<Integer> second = Arrays.asList(new Integer[] {4,7,8});
        ListMergeByRef merger = new ListMergeByRef(ref);
        List<Integer> mergedList = merger.mergeLists(first, second);
        for (Integer element: mergedList) {
            System.out.print(element+" ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
```

Comment: @antoinecaron is there anything else I could do? It seems that you accepted the answer, but then removed the tick a few hours later.

Comment: it s a mistake, I tick it again! I made some changes to your solution because if you switch listA and listB, there is few issues.

Answer (score 1):

```
private static List<String> mergeListsUsingRef(List<String> listRefRaw,
        List<String> listA, List<String> listB) {
    List<String> listRef = uniques(listRefRaw);
    Set<String> common = new HashSet<>();
    common.addAll(listA);
    common.addAll(listB);
    List<String> result = new ArrayList<>(listRef);
    result.retainAll(common);
    return result;
}
```

If the reference list is huge compared to both lists:

```
    return listRef.stream()
            .filter(common::contains)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

This will keep the order of the reference list. The main problem here is that
both listA and listB are not sets, so there is no fast contains-check possible.

```
private static List<String> uniques(List<String> listRefRaw) {
     Set<String> uniqueValues = new HashSet<>();
     return listRefRaw.stream()
         .filter(s -> !uniqueValues.contains(s))
         .peek(uniqueValues::add)
         .collect(Collectors.toList());
}
```

The `Stream.distinct()` unfortunately is not stable on unordered collections,
so the above should do.

Comment: Since the second block uses streams, you should include how to build `common` with streams too, e.g.: `Set<String> common = Stream.concat(listA.stream(), listB.stream()).collect(Collectors.toSet());`

Comment: @Andreas Stream usage could naively use a suboptimal data structure List instead of Set.

Comment: @antoinecaron I wrongly assumed assumed the reference list to determine the order and be unique. I'll repair my answer.

Comment: @JoopEggen Huh? Where could stream usage use `List` instead of `Set`? The `toSet()` call mandates the use of `Set`.

Comment: @Andreas the listA and listB are Lists, and a List.contains is inferior to Set.contains. If you do mean to convert listA and listB into sets per Stream, that would make the code not one simple `stream()`-chain.

Comment: @JoopEggen Perhaps you should read my first comment again. To clarify, your 2nd code block uses a `common` variable that hasn't been defined. In the 1st code block, a variable by that name is built using non-stream code. I'm suggesting to show that same code, but using streams, in 2nd code block, and I included what that stream-code could look like. Since the code I showed doesn't have any `contains` calls, it is obviously not a replacement for the existing code in 2nd code block.

Comment: @Andreas you are so right; I somehow did not read to the end at the appearance of next comment. Thanks for your endurance.

Comment: @JoopEggen; thanks for your anwsers but it's not yet fully compliant. I added some explainations about examples

Comment: @antoinecaron I leave it at this, not out of disrespect, but I got to work / have a living too. It shows that a handling of data needs meticulous, careful programming.

Comment: @JoopEggen thanks for taking time out of your schedules to help me :)

Answer (score 1):

The first two tests fail, because your expected lists are missing the second 4. There are two 4s present in the lists to be merged.

Well anyways, I just went through the ref and removed any matching items from the lists that are attempting to be merged.

```java
public static <E extends Comparable<E>>List<E> merge(List<E> refList, List<E>... lists) {
    List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
    Iterator<E> ref = refList.iterator();
    boolean found = false;
    while (ref.hasNext()) {
        E curr = ref.next();
        found = false; // Reset
        for (List<E> list : lists) {
            if (found) continue; // If already found, skip the next list
            for (Iterator<E>it = list.iterator(); !found && it.hasNext();) {
                E term = it.next();
                boolean equal = term.equals(curr);
                if (equal) {
                    result.add(term);
                    list.remove(term);
                    found = true;
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

### Full Example

```java
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Iterator;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.ListIterator;

public class ListReferenceJoiner {
    public static final boolean DEBUG = true;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.printf("Equal? %b%n", test1());
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.printf("Equal? %b%n", test2());
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.printf("Equal? %b%n", test3());
        System.out.println("===================");
        System.out.printf("Equal? %b%n", test4());
    }

    private static boolean test1() {
        List<Integer> refList = asArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> listA = asArrayList(2, 3, 5, 4, 7);
        List<Integer> listB = asArrayList(4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> expected = asArrayList(2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8);

        return testRunner(refList, listA, listB, expected); // 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8
    }

    private static boolean test2() {
        List<Integer> refList = asArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> listA = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 7);
        List<Integer> listB = asArrayList(4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> expected = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8);

        return testRunner(refList, listA, listB, expected); // 2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8
    }

    private static boolean test3() {
        List<Integer> refList = asArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> listA = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 7);
        List<Integer> listB = asArrayList(6, 4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> expected = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8);

        return testRunner(refList, listA, listB, expected); // 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8
    }

    private static boolean test4() {
        List<Integer> refList = asArrayList(1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> listA = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 7);
        List<Integer> listB = asArrayList(6, 7, 8);
        List<Integer> expected = asArrayList(2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);

        return testRunner(refList, listA, listB, expected); // 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8
    }

    private static boolean testRunner(List<Integer> ref, List<Integer> listA, List<Integer> listB, List<Integer> expected) {
        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.printf("Expecting: %s%n", expected);
        }

        List<Integer> actual = merge(ref, listA, listB); // 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8

        if (DEBUG) {
            System.out.printf("Actual: %s%n", actual);
        }

        return expected.equals(actual);
    }


    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    public static <E extends Comparable<E>>List<E> merge(List<E> refList, List<E>... lists) {
        List<E> result = new ArrayList<E>();
        Iterator<E> ref = refList.iterator();
        boolean found = false;
        while (ref.hasNext()) {
            if (DEBUG) {
                printLists(lists);
            }
            E curr = ref.next();
            found = false; // Reset
            for (List<E> list : lists) {
                if (found) continue; // If already found, skip the next list
                for (Iterator<E>it = list.iterator(); !found && it.hasNext();) {
                    E term = it.next();
                    boolean equal = term.equals(curr);
                    if (equal) {
                        if (DEBUG) {
                            System.out.printf("Found '%s'%n", term);
                        }
                        result.add(term);
                        list.remove(term);
                        found = true;
                    }
                }
            }
            if (DEBUG && !found) {
                System.out.printf("Could not find '%s'%n", curr);
            }
        }
        return result;
    }

    private static <E> void printLists(List<E>... lists) {
        for (ListIterator< List<E>>it = Arrays.asList(lists).listIterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            printList(it.next(), getCharForNumber(it.nextIndex()));
        }
    }

    private static <E> void printList(List<E> list, String label) {
        System.out.printf("%s: ", label);
        for (Iterator< E>it = list.iterator(); it.hasNext();) {
            System.out.print(it.next());
            if (it.hasNext()) {
                System.out.print(" | ");
            }
        }
        System.out.print(System.lineSeparator());
    }

    @SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
    private static <E> List<E> asArrayList(E... values) {
        return new ArrayList<E>(Arrays.asList(values));
    }

    protected static String getCharForNumber(int i) {
        return i > 0 && i < 27 ? String.valueOf((char) (i + 64)) : null;
    }
}
```

Here is a version of Maurice Perry's response, but it still does not preserve order.

```java
private static <E> List<E> merge(final List<E> listRef, final List<E>... lists) {
    final List<E> res = new ArrayList<E>();
    final List<List<E>> copies = Arrays.stream(lists).map(ArrayList::new).collect(Collectors.toList());
    for (E ref : listRef) {
      boolean found = false;
      for (Iterator<List<E>> it = copies.iterator(); !found && it.hasNext();) {
        if (it.next().remove(ref)) {
              res.add(ref);
              found = true;
          }
      }
      if (found) {
        continue;
      }
    }
    return res;
}
```

### Example Output

```
Testing: [2, 3, 5, 4, 7, 8]
A: 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Could not find '1'
A: 2 | 3 | 5 | 4 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '2'
A: 3 | 5 | 4 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '3'
A: 5 | 4 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '5'
A: 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Could not find '6'
A: 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 7
B: 7 | 8
Found '7'
A: 
B: 7 | 8
Found '8'
Actual: [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8]
Equal? false
===================
Testing: [2, 3, 4, 5, 7, 8]
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Could not find '1'
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '2'
A: 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '3'
A: 4 | 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 5 | 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '5'
A: 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Could not find '6'
A: 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 7
B: 7 | 8
Found '7'
A: 
B: 7 | 8
Found '8'
Actual: [2, 3, 4, 5, 4, 7, 8]
Equal? false
===================
Testing: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8]
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Could not find '1'
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Found '2'
A: 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Found '3'
A: 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 5 | 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Found '5'
A: 7
B: 6 | 4 | 7 | 8
Found '6'
A: 7
B: 4 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 7
B: 7 | 8
Found '7'
A: 
B: 7 | 8
Found '8'
Actual: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 4, 7, 8]
Equal? true
===================
Testing: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Could not find '1'
A: 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Found '2'
A: 3 | 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Found '3'
A: 4 | 5 | 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Found '4'
A: 5 | 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Found '5'
A: 7
B: 6 | 7 | 8
Found '6'
A: 7
B: 7 | 8
Could not find '4'
A: 7
B: 7 | 8
Found '7'
A: 
B: 7 | 8
Found '8'
Actual: [2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8]
Equal? true
```

Answer (score 1):

Your code works correctly!

There are however 2 issues:

- Your logic doesn't need the null checks.

  Since `equals(null)` is [required](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals-java.lang.Object-) to return `false`, you can safely reduce `if (a != null && ref.equals(a))` to just `if (ref.equals(a))`
- Your expectation for EX 1 is incorrect.

  The values match up like this:

  ```
  ref:    "1", "2", "3", "4", "5", "6", "4", "7", "8"
  ---------------------------------------------------
  A:           "2", "3",      "5",      "4", "7"
  B:                     "4",                "7", "8"
  ===================================================
  result:      "2", "3", "4", "5",      "4", "7", "8"
  ```

  But you're expecting

  ```
               "2", "3",      "5",      "4", "7", "8"
  ```

  As you can see, you should be expecting the first **4** too.